# Probability of 7 straight roulette wheel spins within same group of 12 numbers

Tags: probability

What are the odds of 7 straight spins on a roulette wheel rendering a number within the same group of 12 numbers? (i.e. 7 numbers within 1-12, 7 within 13-24 or 7 within 25-36).  This would be a natural streak of 7 straight within the same group and no spins hitting 0 or 00.

Thank you for your help!

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are three groups, they're all the same size, so you have the same probability of hitting each of them, $\frac 1 3$, assuming the roulette wheel is fair.

I suggest using the [binomial probability formula](http://www.mathwords.com/b/binomial_probability_formula.htm). Out of seven trials, you want seven successes, with a success probability of $\frac 1 3$ each. This should be sufficient to let you find the answer.

(Note that you do not need to distinguish between the groups. The group that you need to hit for a "success" is just the group you hit on the first trial.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the no. of nos. on the wheel. Assuming there are 38 nos. - 0, 00 and 1-36 (each with equal chance of occurence), the probability is [(12/38)^7]*3 = 0.00093 (approx.)

Comment: Simulation shows the probability to be be about $0.001376$. You are almost certainly wrong.